# How to access "calculated" methods from scala case class in Spark 2.0 dataset?

Tags: scala, case-class, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

## Context

This blog post seems to offer a great way to work with closely related scala case classes in a spark dataset (see the last section: "The Solution"): https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/07/spark-2-0-datasets-case-classes/

Essentially, I'm trying to get a "calculated" field like this:

```
trait HasVolume extends HasThreeDimensions {
 def volume = width * height * depth
}
```

I tried implementing my case classes with traits like the author does. However, they do not specify how I would be able to then access those "calculated" methods such as `volume` **from within the dataset.**

## Questions

1. What would you call these "calculated" trait methods such as
   `volume` that are set equal to an expression?
2. After I've casted a dataset with the resulting case class (that extends the trait above), how would I access those "calculated" trait methods?
3. Would it be simpler to use Scala Maps instead of case classes? What's the advantage of case classes?

Comment: There's nothing special about that method, it is used like any other.  What specifically is giving you trouble?

Comment: @puhlen, I've messed around with this some more and I actually can access the data if I `take` object (row) out of the dataframe and then call the method from the object. However, it does not appear as a column if I `show` the dataset. So, I'm guessing I could make UDF's that refer to it in the dataset, but the method is "hidden" in the sense that it will never be shown as a column. Does that sound right?

Comment: Sorry, I think this question was a red herring. I just tested one of my "regular" methods and had the same issue. Specifically, I was trying to use a map function like in the blog (`ds.map(_.color)`) on the dataset and getting a NPE. It was because I have Null fields in some records from my source (hive query).

Comment: FWIW, it turned out my cluster configuration wasn't working. When I switched to local mode on 4 cores, everything worked fine. So the NPE had nothing to do with these methods I was editing at the time.